# Mapping IdentityUser derived to a concrete class with AutoMapper

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a simple AspNetCore Web Api with 2 entities a Product and a Person which derives from IdentityUser

```
public class Product 
{
 public int Id {get;set;}
public string Name {get; set;}
public Person Person {get; set; }
} 
public class Person : IdentityUser
{
public string FirstName {get; set;}
}
```

And the ViewModel and the AutoMapper profile

```
public class ProductVM
{
 public string Name {get; set;}
 public string PersonWhoAdded {get;set;}
}
public class ProductProfile : Profile 


{
      public ProductProfile()
      {
       CreateMap<Product, ProductVM>()
        .ForMember(p=> PersonWhoAdded , opt.MapFrom(model=>model.Person.FirstName)).ReverseMap();
      }}
```

And here is my repo

```
`public class ProductRepo: IProductRepo
{
   public IEnumerable<Product> GetProducts()
    {
      return context.ProductSet.Include(p=> p.Person).ToList(); 
    }
}`
```

And my controller

```
  [Route("api/[controller]")
public class ProductController: Controller
   { 
      IMapper _mapper;
       ctor(mapper){
        _mapper=mapper;  
        }
      [HttpGet]
      public IActionResult Get()
      {
        IEnumerable<Product> _products = _repo.GetProducts();
        // omitted Status codes for simplicity
        return Ok(_mapper.Map<IEnumerable<ProductVM>>(_products);

      }
   }
```

The problem is it shows me null on personWhoAdded instead of the FirstName 
   I can authenticate and do PUSH from different users after I register and login but if I want a get to list the products and the firstName of the User it shows me null ... 
Maybe there's a different approach but I am not an expert so any help would do
Thanks

Comment: If you examine `_repo.GetProducts().ToList()` in the debugger, are `Person` properties populated (not `null`)?

Comment: @IvanStoev ... I am running VS Code on a Windows7 32bit machine so debugging is not an option (at least thats what I know )), I ll recreate the same example in VS 2013 and have a look ..Anyway thanks for the hint